# cURL: Notoken-Error on import to mediawiki

Tags: curl, import, csrf, mediawiki-api

I am trying to import a page into mediawiki with curl. However, I do not know how to handover the csrf token via multipart/form-data. Editing a page with prependtext works fine, so I am logged in and have a valid csrf token.

The command so far is

curl --cookie tmp/COOKIE_JAR 
--cookie-jar tmp/COOKIE_JAR 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "=xml=<tmp/import.xml" 
${WIKI}/api.php?action=import&format=json

$pur contains the token (ending with backslash)

What I tried is:

- Append &token=$pur (mustpostparams-error)
- -H "Token: $pur" (notoken)
- -F "token=$pur" (notoken)

Could you please tell me the line that works?

Thank you in advance!